# How to keep two Hadoop versions on Ubuntu?

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm running some tests and I need to be able to go back and forth between two different versions of Hadoop - the 2.2.0 release and a customized one by me. However, I'm having trouble setting their variables at ~/.bashrc - if I have both of them at the same time, it will conflict. I'm only able to run the 2.2.0 release, not mine.
However, if I comment the variables related to the 2.2.0 version at ~/.bashrc, it will run my version.
Here are my Hadoop-related variables from ~/.bashrc:

```
#Hadoop variables - my version 
export HADOOPTWO_INSTALL=/home/parallels/Development/Hadoop/hadoop-trunk/trunk2/hadoop-dist/target/hadoop-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOPTWO_INSTALL/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOPTWO_INSTALL/sbin
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOPTWO_INSTALL
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOPTWO_INSTALL
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOPTWO_INSTALL
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOPTWO_INSTALL
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOPTWO_INSTALL/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS -Djava.library.path=$HADOOPTWO_INSTALL/lib/"


#Hadoop variables - version 2.2.0
export HADOOP_INSTALL=/home/parallels/Development/Hadoop/hadoop-2.2.0
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/sbin
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS -Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib/"
```

If I run `$HADOOPTWO_INSTALL/bin/hadoop version`, which calls my version's hadoop file, it will return:

```
Hadoop 2.2.0
Subversion https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common -r 1529768
Compiled by hortonmu on 2013-10-07T06:28Z
Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
From source with checksum 79e53ce7994d1628b240f09af91e1af4
This command was run using /home/parallels/Development/Hadoop/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.2.0.jar
```

Which is obviously wrong, given the location of the jar called on the command (it is still calling the jar from the 2.2.0 version, even though I specifically called my customized Hadoop version).

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I've done in similar situations where I have to have multiple, conflicting environments is to encapsulate them into functions:

```
function my-hadoop-env {
    #Hadoop variables - my version 
    export HADOOPTWO_INSTALL=/home/parallels/Development/Hadoop/hadoop-trunk/trunk2/hadoop-dist/target/hadoop-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT
    export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOPTWO_INSTALL/bin
    export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOPTWO_INSTALL/sbin
    export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOPTWO_INSTALL
    export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOPTWO_INSTALL
    export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOPTWO_INSTALL
    export YARN_HOME=$HADOOPTWO_INSTALL
    export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOPTWO_INSTALL/lib/native
    export HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS -Djava.library.path=$HADOOPTWO_INSTALL/lib/"
}

function hadoop-env {
    #Hadoop variables - version 2.2.0
    export HADOOP_INSTALL=/home/parallels/Development/Hadoop/hadoop-2.2.0
    export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/bin
    export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/sbin
    export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
    export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
    export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
    export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
    export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib/native
    export HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS -Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib/"
}
```

Then when opening a shell, execute the appropriate `my-hadoop-env` or `hadoop-env` function to pull in the environment you want in that shell.

If you're feeling crafty you can even make them modify `PS1` so it's clear which one your'e in.

Comment: So I just have to call "my-hadoop-env" when I open a shell, right? What do you mean by modifying PS1?

Comment: Cool, I think I've got it... that's exactly the type of thing I was hoping for. Thanks, man!

Answer (score 0):

I would say you are overwriting your HADOOPTWO path variables with the hadoop 2.2.0 path. You can only export 1 PATH variable and if your .bashrc executes in the order you have posted above then your path should look like this

```
/home/parallels/Development/Hadoop/hadoop-2.2.0/bin
```

Comment: I've tried to swap the order, but it did not change... even when I putted my version's variables after 2.2.0, it would still call 2.2.0, which is odd...

Answer (score 0):

What I've done to switch between versions is to put the different hadoop versions into different directories and create a symbolic link to the one that I want to be active.  That way all the configs always refer to the same location.

```
ln -s /usr/local/hadoop-versions/hadoop-2.2.0 /usr/local/hadoop
```